# Односвязный список c++. Обратный порядок элементов

Tags: c++, односвязный-список

У меня есть код, которые выполняет следующее задание: вводятся построчно символы до точки, потом выводится список. Мне нужно добавить такой метод, чтобы при его вызове список дополнился всеми его символами в обратном порядке(например был список абс. должен стать абс.сба). Разворачивать список нельзя. Метод должен быть основан на таком принципе: проходим снова с первого элемента по списку и добавляем каждый раз элемент после точки(сначала абс.а, потом абс.ба, потом абс.сба). Я попытался написать функцию AddElements, но окончательно запутался в ней, или ловлю бесконечный цикл с пустым выводом или наоборот бесконечным выводом, или выводится только первый символ

Вот мой код

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <vector>


struct element {
    char x;
    element* Next;
};

class List {
    element* Head;
public:
    List() {
        Head = NULL;
    }
    ~List();

    void Add(char x, element*& Head);
    void Show(element* Beg);
    void AddElements(element* beg, element*& Head);

};

List::~List() {
    while (Head != NULL) {
        element* temp = Head->Next;
        delete Head;
        Head = temp;
    }
}

std::vector <char> v;

void List::Add(char x, element*& Head) {
    element* temp = new element;
    temp->x = x;
    temp->Next = NULL;
    Head->Next = temp;
    Head = temp;
}


void List::Show(element* beg) {
    element* temp = beg;
    for (auto i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        std::cout << temp->x << "";
        temp = temp->Next;
    }
    Head = beg;
}

void List::AddElements(element* beg, element*& Head) {
    element* temp1 = beg;
    element* temp2 = Head;
    element* temp0 = temp1;
    temp2->Next = temp0;
    while (temp1 != temp2) {
        temp0->Next = temp2->Next;
        temp0 = temp1;
        temp2->Next = temp0;
        
        if (temp1->Next != NULL) {
            temp1 = temp1->Next;
        }
    }

}

int main() {
    system("chcp 1251");
    std::cout << "Односвязный список." << std::endl;
    char x;
    List lst;
    element* H = new element;
    element* beg = H;
    std::cout << "Введите символ: "; std::cin >> x;
    v.insert(v.begin(), x);
    H->x = x;
    H->Next = NULL;
    while (x != '.') {
        std::cin >> x;
        lst.Add(x, H);
    }
    lst.AddElements(beg, H);
    std::cout << "Результат: ";
    lst.Show(beg);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне кажется, что построение отдельного списка из символов первого в обратном порядке, а потом добавление всего его в конец первого списка будет самым простым решением.

Вот код в стиле Си, иллюстрирующий такой подход (на кресты с объектами при желании переделайте сами)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct element {
  char x;
  struct element *next;
};

void
print_list (const char *msg, struct element *list)
{
  printf("%s", msg);
  while (list) {
    printf("%c", list->x);
    list = list->next;
  }
  puts("");
}

    
int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  struct element *list = 0;
  struct element **p = &list; // pointer to the last element in the `list`
  int c;

  // let's build a list in direct order (in John Carmack style)
  while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    *p = (__typeof__(*p))malloc(sizeof(**p));
    (*p)->x = c;
    (*p)->next = 0;
    if (c == '.')
      break;
    p = &((*p)->next);
  }

  print_list("Source list: ", list);

  struct element *rlist = 0;

  // build another list from the elements of the first one
  // up to the point in reverse order
  for (struct element *t = list; t && t->x != '.'; t = t->next) {
    struct element *q = (__typeof__(q))malloc(sizeof(*q));
    q->x = t->x;
    q->next = rlist;
    rlist = q;
  }

  print_list("Revert head list: ", rlist);

  // add the second list to the end of the first for get the result
  (*p)->next = rlist;
  print_list("Result list: ", list);
  
  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

Компилируем и проверяем:

```
avp@avp-xubu2:~/hashcode$ g++ t.c && ./a.out
abc.
Source list: abc.
Revert head list: cba
Result list: abc.cba
End
avp@avp-xubu2:~/hashcode$
```

Вариант без построения промежуточного списка. В этом случае мы вместо вставки копий элементов первого списка во второй будем просто помещать их после элемента с '.' в обратном порядке (на этот элемент указывает `(*p)`)

```
int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  struct element *list = 0;
  struct element **p = &list; // pointer to the last element in the `list`
  int c;

  // let's build a list in direct order
  while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    *p =(__typeof__(*p))malloc(sizeof(**p));
    (*p)->x = c;
    (*p)->next = 0;
    if (c == '.')
      break;
    p = &((*p)->next);
  }

  print_list("Source list: ", list);

  // let's add list elements up to the element with '.' (`*p` is the pointer to it)
  // after it in reverse order
  for (struct element *t = list; t && t->x != '.'; t = t->next) {
    struct element *q = (__typeof__(q))malloc(sizeof(*q));
    q->x = t->x;

    q->next = (*p)->next;
    (*p)->next = q;

  }
 
  print_list("Result list: ", list);
  
  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, я думал об этом, но так нельзя( Нельзя создавать новый список, или использовать строку или вектор. Обязательно изменить нужно именно этот список, расширив его, каждый раз вставляя элементы после точки

Comment: Тогда попробуйте изменить цикл for. Если в нем заменить `rlist` на `(*p)` (это выражение указывает на `next` в последнем элементе списка с  '.'), то на первый взгляд должно получиться. (сейчас уже поздно, я только завтра вечером смогу проверить)

Comment: Основное задание - сохранить структуру кода, я сделал это, добавив вашу функцию. Но если менять теперь rlist на H, то выводится просто исходный список до точки, либо я уже просто запутался и что-то вероятно делаю не так. Вот код, с функцией, которую, я добавил https://codeshare.io/loKjYB

Comment: Я добавил изменения. Теперь `rlist` не нужен.

Comment: В вашем коде (по ссылке на codeshare) надо выбросить все с `rlist` и внутри цикла for вместо `q->Next = rlist;       rlist = q;` написать `q->Next = H->Next; H->Next = q;`. Все работает. (только в Show у вас я бы  добавил печать '\n' в конце)

Comment: Спасибо большое, что помогли разобраться! Очень долго мучался над этой задачей

Comment: Рад за вас.  Могу только посоветовать самому попридумывать и поделать аналогичные задачки (вставить перед заданным элементом, после него, удалить из списка, реверсировать список, слить 2 списка и т.п.) со списками, лучше без классов, т.е. напрямую манипулируя указателями.